# Is there a way to change environment for specific method in controller? - CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp

For example I want to test my **method** on my local **environment** with the DB from **production** environment. Is it possible to set/change env(**local/staging/production**) in the **method** or before **method** in specific **controller**?

Using **CakePHP** version **2.2.9**

Answer (score 0):

**Yes...!!!**

you can make a condition in your configure file

Make a individual path of your Local/Staging/Production folder

```
$servername = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
if($servername == 'localhost'){
    define('SITE_PATH','http://YourLocalWebsite');  
} else if($servername == 'Dev.yourwebsite') {
    define('SITE_PATH','http://StagingYourwebsite');    
} else {
    define('SITE_PATH','http://YourWebsite');   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question. I solved it by temporarily putting the same database.php file from production to staging - for retrieving data (just have to run some tests).